# Logic Help needed for list manipulation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, list

I need small help. I have 2 lists( say A and B) which have objects of a user defined class.

Both A and B have a method getId() which would return an integer (ID). Now, I need to compare the ID of every object in List A with each and every object of List B. If the ID is same then I have to replace that object from B with that of A.

If the id of the object from A is not in B then I would add that object to B

Please provide me a logic on how to achive this

Thanks

Comment: i have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977658/concurrentmodificationexception-help-in-iterator#comment12748686_9977658

Comment: But the problem is it is checking for the each and every object in A with all objects in B and if its not same its adding the objects again and again

Comment: i just want to see if B contains the current object in A if yes then replace that object with this else just add it

Comment: @SimonC Any Ideas how this can be acheived ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work, assuming your list is an arrayList with the possibility to access elements with an index

```
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    for(int j=0;j<b.size();j++)
       if(a.get(i).getId().equals(b.get(j).getId()){
         //this id from A exists in B. Replace
         b.get(j)=a.get(i);
       }
       else{
          if(j=(b.size()+1)){ // if true the whole b list have been searched
             //object not found. Add it to b
             b.add(a.get(i));      
          } 
}
```

This requiers that your elements in a and b override the equals statment, so they can compare the ID with eachother

Comment: thanks, but the problem is suppose the list A has {1,2,3}(consider 1,2,3 are the id's of the object) and B has {5,6,7}, now 1 will be compared with 5 and it will not match and will be added to B, and again 1 will be compared with 6 and again it would be added, and it goes on, what i need it if B contains an object of A then it has to be replaced with A, or else just add

Comment: Oh, you are correct on that. One solution would be to break; in the else statement. This would break out of the inner loop, which means that the first loop and set i to 1. So, if you have as you said a={1, 2, 3} and b={5,6,7} then 1 gets compared with 5, no match so it adds 1 to b, breaks out of the loop and now 2 will be compared with 5 which is what you want

Comment: I really appriciate your help Jimmy, That's a good logic, but there is a small loop hole , if suppose b={5,6,7,1} , 1 will be checked with 5 and it will break out. But there is a match at the fourth position. :(

Comment: if we can try with  continue statement if it dont match , and after reaching the end of list can we add it to the list???

Comment: add another if inside the else statement: if(j=(b.size()+1)) then do b.add and break. This will ensure that the j list have reached it's last element

Comment: Actually, you will not need the break at all. If you look at my edited post this should work :)

Comment: in the code above j=(b.size()+1) will never be statisfied so i had it like j+1=(b.size()), is it fine?

Comment: Yeah that must be correct. size will return the number of elements in the array. so if you have 5 elements it will return 5, altho the index for those are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. This means when you are checking the 5th element (index 4) j will be 4 since it starts at 0. So either do j+1 or b.size()-1

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Hashtable in place of List. You can give ID as a key for each object.

Comment: Assuming the ID is unique for the objects involved, this is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an interface for the getID() method:

```
public interface Identity {    
     public long getID();
}
```

And now we do the trick to sync both lists:

```
private List<Identity> listA = new ArrayList();
private List<Identity> listB = new ArrayList();

private void syncLists() {
    final Map<Long, Identity> map = new HashMap();

    // add all elements of list b
    for ( Identity element : this.listB ) {
        map.put( element.getID(), element );
    }

    // add all elements of list a, overwrite the existing ones of b
    for ( Identity element : this.listA ) {
        map.put( element.getID(), element );
    }

    // write the elements of the map back into the lists
    this.listA = new ArrayList( map.values() );
    this.listB = new ArrayList( map.values() );
    // list a contains the same references as list b now
}
```

I assumed that equals() is not overwritten for your objects!

Answer (score 1):

Sample program I had created. Hope this might help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> A = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<User> B = new ArrayList<User>();
    A.add(new User(1, "A1"));
    A.add(new User(2, "A2"));
    A.add(new User(3, "A3"));

    B.add(new User(1, "B1"));
    B.add(new User(4, "B4"));
    B.add(new User(5, "B5"));

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++) {
            if (A.get(i).getId() == B.get(j).getId()) {
                B.remove(j);
                B.add(j, A.get(i));
            } else {
                if (!B.contains(A.get(i))) {
                    B.add(A.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-----Finally------");
    for (User u : A)
        System.out.println("From A-->" + u.getName());
    for (User u : B)
        System.out.println("From B-->" + u.getName());

}
```

And class User is:

```
class User {
public int id;
public String name;

User(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

But using Map is advisable !!!